# webView.loading for OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, load

I wrote a iOS app. Now I want to make the same for mac osx.
For iPhone I wrote:

```
if (myWebView.loading) {
    //code
}
else {
    // other code
}
```

But for OS X the `.loading` does not work. It is not a UIWebView!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a good idea to read the reference on WebView, for OS X, before continuing - ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

You're looking for `WebView`'s `-(BOOL)isLoading`, so:

```
if ([myWebView isLoading]) {
    // do something
}
```